# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_var()

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to select data from Magento database and it doesn't work. I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_var()

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

function jal_install() {
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "fees";
}

$results = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT service_fee FROM $table_name WHERE max >= $amount AND min = $amount");
echo $results['service_fee'];
?>
```

Comment: get_var seems to be wordpress function, What are you trying to implement?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the value of results through ajax.